# Authentication Issues when Updating CSV File in GitHub Repository from Webpage: Token and SHA

Tags: javascript, github

I am currently developing a webpage using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, incorporating an HTML form. The objective is to update a CSV file in my GitHub repository when a user clicks a button on the webpage. However, I am encountering authentication issues, specifically with tokens and SHA, as GitHub removes the token authorization each time I attempt to update the file.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to address this specific issue and ensure that information is updated correctly in the repository without losing token authorization? Or is there another way to upload the updated CSV file to the repository? I appreciate any guidance or solutions you can provide.

I have attempted to use tokens and SHA for authentication during the update process. My expectation was that the information from the form would be seamlessly added to the CSV file in the repository. However, the recurring removal of token authorization by GitHub has hindered the successful execution of this process.

Comment: What is your code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're checking the token into your code.  GitHub has secret scanning enabled, so if you check any of a variety of secrets, not just GitHub tokens, into your code, they'll be automatically revoked.  This is good, because secrets don't belong in code; they belong in secret stores instead.

GitHub especially does not want GitHub tokens leaked because then bad actors use them to do malicious things, which is bad for the users and companies who have the secret exposed, bad for other users who can be impacted by spam and abuse from that token, bad for the support team who has to help those users and explain the impact, and bad for the abuse teams who have to deal with the spam and abuse.  It's just really terrible for everyone.

Now, if the reason you're doing that is because you have a static site, then the answer is that there's no secure way to use a static site with secrets that the user should not have.  That's because everything in a static site goes to the user, and the user should not have access to your personal access token.  You need a backend to do this securely, and the backend would hold the secret.

If you do have a backend and need the secret when deploying, the right way to do this is to use something like the GitHub Actions secret store to inject it when deploying.  That way, it's stored in an encrypted form and you can prevent it from being leaked or exposed.